# The general relation between the coordinates and any given vector in row and column space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a Basis.

Would like to get the general relation between a Vector and Coordinates (of the basis).

There are two ways, the first is to put the Basis vectors as ***columns*** in a matrix. Looks to be the easier way. All Clear here.

The second way is to put the vectors of the basis in a matrix as ***rows***, reduce and use the pivots only. (not the free members of the matrix).  Look to be the harder way, would like to understand this way better.

My questions regarding second method:

1. Why doesn't the free member of row base matrix  used in the coordinates of the vector (b3 in the image) , intuition for that? Does it have something to do with Q? - the row reduction operation matrix R = QA.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to follow the question.. Not clear what you're trying to achieve by row-reducing $A^T$. If you're trying to solve equations (find $x$), then what would $y$ mean? How come $y$ starts as a vector and ends up to be a matrix? I assume you meant to augment $A^T$ with $I$ not with $y$. Could you re-phrase your question? Ideally use MathJax instead of pictures.

Comment: Just trying to find the relations between the coordinates and general vector.
Linear Algebra - Hoffman, Kunze.
For the full solution https://www.math.pku.edu.cn/teachers/anjp/textbook.pdf  
(page 70 in the pdf)